# Image doesn't fit to circular image view

Tags: android, image

I'm trying to create a circular image view and used all libraries that available at this moment on github. At the end I tried this solution:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".CompanyActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true">

            <com.example.bydlokoder.empatika.utils.BezelImageView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/logo_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_height"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:elevation="1dp"
                app:biv_maskDrawable="@drawable/circle_mask"
                />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/company_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="@string/company_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/company_name_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/company_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/company_name"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_doubled_vertical_margin"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="@string/company_description"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/company_description_text_size"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/call_button"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
                android:layout_below="@+id/company_description"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_doubled_vertical_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/button_style"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/button_left_padding"
                android:text="@string/call_button"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_button"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
                android:layout_below="@+id/call_button"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/button_style"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/button_left_padding"
                android:text="@string/email_button"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/copyright"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/email_button"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_doubled_vertical_margin"
                android:text="@string/company_copyright"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/company_copyright_text_size" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Bit it gives me the same image that doesn't look well
[image: bad icon]

I think that google should provide standart view for this purpose...
Any ideas how to solve this?

Java class can be found there [BezelImageView](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/BezelImageView.java)

Comment: Add a white border around the image OR make the circle smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the image circular within a transparent/alpha square image area. There is no need to have a circular image view this way. Just an example below (save in PNG format with alpha/transparency)

http://dfoolonthehill.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/ScreenHunter_16-Jun.-13-19.21.jpg

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: You may edit code of custom imageview, and calculate and scale bitmap on draw method, where it draw canvas.

Answer (score 0):

It just because of the imageview don't maintain scale type, it just draw your bitmap to canvas with masking.
That's why image not fit to imageview.